# How to print the value of BigDecimals within a hash as to_s

Tags: ruby

I have a hash `x`. I want to print the hash `x`, but for those values that are `BigDecimal`, I would like to print their `to_s` conversions. I need an expression to return a single string; it can't be a series of separate `puts` or `print` in `loop`. Maybe with `join`. Can I do this easily in one line or so?

Comment: By saying you have a hash 'X' (a capital letter) means it is a constant, which is probably not what you mean (though it's irrelevant).  Better to just drop the reference to 'X' and just say, "a hash" or a hash `h` ('h' with backticks before and after). Backticks around `.to_s` would also be good.  Also, your second sentence is unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland for the suggestions. I made the edit.

Comment: You added an additional requirement in a comment below.  It's better to edit your question and refer to the edit in your comment.  When you make such an edit, make it clear that it is an edit, so the original statement of the question remains unchanged.  Some begin such an edit **Edit:..** (i.e., "Edit:" in bold face).

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not specified what string to join the result with, I assume you want to join with `""`, which is the default. `join` will automatically apply `to_s`.

```
puts x.values.grep(BigDecimal).join
```

I may have mistaken the question since it is not clear. If you wanted to print all values, but apply `to_s` to certain values, then you do not need special operation because `join` will apply `to_s` automatically.

```
puts x.values.join
```

Comment: @steenslag Thanks for the information. I edited the answer following your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
X.each do |key, value|
   value.class == BigDecimal ? puts value.to_s : puts value
end
```

or

```
X.each { |key, value | value.class == BigDecimal ? puts value.to_s : puts value }
```

Check out the ternary operator.

Edit:

Also in regards to your edited question requesting one string:

`new_array = X.map {|object| object.class == BigDecimal ? object.to_s : object }` then turn it into a string with `new_array.join("")`

Comment: You could replace the block variable, `key`, with `_` or (say) `_key` (as it is not used) and move `puts` before `value.class == BigDecimal`.

Comment: ... Also I need this expression to return a single string expression. So it can't be a series of separate puts. Any help?

Comment: To add it to a string I would create an array object and replace puts with adding to array it such as `array = [] X.each { |key, value | value.class == BigDecimal ? array << value.to_s : array << value }`. Than you can return the array.

Comment: I would also suggest using the more rubyist .map enumerable instead of X.each. `new_array = X.map {|object| object.class == BigDecimal ? object.to_s : object }` then turn it into a string with `new_array.join("")`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all key/value pairs and perform a simple type check:

```
X.each do |k, v|
  v.is_a?(BigDecimal) ?  puts v.to_s : puts v
end
```

Instead of [`is_a?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) you can also use [`instance_of?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_of-3F).

**EDIT**

To fit your ***new requirements***, first build an array using [map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-map) for [values](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values):

```
strArr = X.values.map { | v | v.is_a?(BigDecimal) ?  v.to_s : v }
```

Now create a string from the array using [join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
myStr = strArr.join("[SEPARATING CHARACTER]")
```

Comment: ... Also I need this expression to return a single string expression. So it can't be a series of separate puts. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers do a good job of printing the values, but are not returning a single string as OP requested. I recommend using map to first place the resultant values in an array, and then a join (with your delimiter of choice).

```
    values_array = x.map{ |k,v| v.is_a?(BigDecimal) ? v.to_s : v }
    values_string = values_array.join(",")
```

You can also do the `.join` method at the end of the map block, but I thought I'd keep it separate for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

```
"{" + (x.map {|key, value| "#{key}: #{value.is_a?(BigDecimal) ? value.to_s("F") : value}" }).join(", ") + "}"
```

Comment: Your requirements were totally unclear to receive such an answer